# JavaFX : rowspan the same value in tableview

Tags: javafx

Hello everyone 
 that's my first question here and i hope to find answers

 as u can  see in the picture below i want the to merge the cells with the same "N° commande" (red in the pic) but i want to keep the rest cells in that row selectable (blue in the pic) for other purpose (modify)

I'm using MySQL database to populate the tableview
is there any trick to do that ?

Thanks a lot

PS. i've searched here and in google and i only found [this](http://fxexperience.com/2012/10/cell-spanning-in-tableview/) but the sample jar not working anymore

[image]

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `TableView`'s `CellSpan` and `RowSpan` functionalities were cut upon release. They may be released in the future.